# Hierarchical indexing of Panda's dataframe using an n-d numpy array for indices

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, multi-index, hierarchical

I need to read parametric data from a csv file into a DataFrame for statistical analysis. I would like to use hierarchical indexing. I have 10 groups of parameters with a total of 70 variations. A sample cut of the excel representation:

[image: Sample Excel representation]

I tried building the df using an n-d nparray to avoid defining the tuples manually but got lost between using arrays, from_product, merging multiple data frames per parameter and so:

```
params = np.array([[['Baseline'], ['orig']]
                       , [['Threshold'], ['Thresh-2', 'Thresh+2', 'Thresh_marg', 'Thresh_cort']]
                       , [['Marker'], ['MHx-2', 'MHx+2', 'MHz-2', 'MHz+2', 'MTx-2', 'MTx+2', 'MTz-2', 'MTz+2', 'MSx-2', 'MSx+2', 'MSz-2', 'MSz+2']]])

rows = []
df = []
paramLen = 0
paramdf = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(params)):
    paramLen += len(params[i][1])
    rows.append(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(params[i]))
    df.append(pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(len(params[i][1])), index = rows[i]))
    paramdf = pd.concat([paramdf, df[i]])
```

Is there a way to use the n-d array directly for indexing?

Answer (score 0):

The target sequence is not a multi-index structure, so as far as I know there is no way to expand it directly. I used your approach to store the indexes in two lists and created a multi-index at the end. I haven't answered the question in a convincing way, but I've answered another way for your reference.

```
import itertools
idx1 = []
idx2 = []
for i in params:
    d = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(i)
    idx1.append(d.get_level_values(0).tolist())
    idx2.append(d.get_level_values(1).tolist())
idx1 = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(idx1))
idx2 = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(idx2))

df = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([idx1, idx2], names=('Parameter','Value'))
df
MultiIndex([( 'Baseline',        'orig'),
            ('Threshold',    'Thresh-2'),
            ('Threshold',    'Thresh+2'),
            ('Threshold', 'Thresh_marg'),
            ('Threshold', 'Thresh_cort'),
            (   'Marker',       'MHx-2'),
            (   'Marker',       'MHx+2'),
            (   'Marker',       'MHz-2'),
            (   'Marker',       'MHz+2'),
            (   'Marker',       'MTx-2'),
            (   'Marker',       'MTx+2'),
            (   'Marker',       'MTz-2'),
            (   'Marker',       'MTz+2'),
            (   'Marker',       'MSx-2'),
            (   'Marker',       'MSx+2'),
            (   'Marker',       'MSz-2'),
            (   'Marker',       'MSz+2')],
           names=['Parameter', 'Value'])
```